# Why is Swift 5 String(Int) Failing when a Big Integer of over 20 digits?

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion, metal, bigint

I wrote the above-referenced simple code to check if integers in the Fibonacci sequence do not contain 0 or 5, and reduce to 1237, if the integer only contains 1,2,3,4,6,7,8, or 9 as digits; and if so, to then print the member of the sequence. Interestingly from a numbers game perspective, there are only 23 such integers in the Fibonacci sequence.

I have to use the [Swift-BigInt](https://github.com/mkrd/Swift-BigInt) library for when the integers get large:

```
func getFib1237s() {
  // Some temporary variables.
  var a = BInt(0)
  var b = BInt(1)
  var m = BInt(1)
  var i = BInt(0)
  var z = BInt(1)
  // Get the numbers until crash...
  while i < z {
    let temp = a
    a = b
    b = b + temp
    print("a: ", a)
    var str = String(a)
    print("String start: ", str)
    str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "9", with: "3")
    print("String after 9 reducto: ", str)
    str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "6", with: "23")
    print("String after 6 reducto: ", str)
    str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "8", with: "2")
    print("String after 8 reducto: ", str)
    str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "4", with: "2")
    print("String after 4 reducto: ", str)
    if (str.firstIndex(of:"5") == nil) && (str.firstIndex(of: "0") == nil) && str.contains("1") && str.contains("2") && str.contains("3") && str.contains("7")  {
            print(m, "Fib 1237 number is ", a, " | Digits: ", str.count)
            m+=1
        }
    i+=1
    z+=1
  }
}
```

Apparently, at or around the 20-digit mark, the `String()` method fails and throws errors, not performing the check, because, according to the debugger, the integer is being changed to random other integer entirely.

So, are there any `BigInt` or `String` workaround/alternatives in Swift? I wrote Ruby code that works fine in Xcode, but am trying to exclusively use Swift (and metal) for this project which ultimately needs to work on iOS for commercial/production purposes.

Comment: Forget about this pod. You should use Swift native `Decimal` type

Comment: Try `a.asString(radix: 10)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce to 1237"? Which 23 integers are you looking for?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want `317811`, `267914296`, `8944394323791464`, `83621143489848422977` and so on?

Comment: Yes, exactly, 317811 is the first one, which incidentally also has an interesting property regarding the convergence on and precision of Phi of the adjacent ratios. The 0 can be in the digits too for the 23, I mistyped that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String(a)` calls the `String.init` overload that takes `BinaryInteger`. It is very possible that this initialiser is not designed to handle numbers that are super large. You can use `a.asString(radix: 10)` to convert to string instead.

To make your code work correctly, you should also:

- remove the `(str.firstIndex(of: "0") == nil)`
- declare a new string variable and assign the replaced strings to it, otherwise `str.count` would be incorrect.

I would recommend writing a separate method called `reduce`, because "reducing" a string requires quite a few steps.

Here is `reduce`:

```
func reduce(_ s: String) -> String {
    let unique = String(Set(s))
    let replaced = unique.replacingOccurrences(of: "9", with: "3")
                                .replacingOccurrences(of: "6", with: "23")
                                .replacingOccurrences(of: "8", with: "2")
                                .replacingOccurrences(of: "4", with: "2")
                                .replacingOccurrences(of: "0", with: "")
    let sortedUniqueAgain = String(Set(replaced).sorted())
    return sortedUniqueAgain
}
```

Now, we can just check whether the return value of this method is 1237:

```
while m <= 23 {
    let temp = a
    a = b
    b = b + temp
    let str = a.asString(radix: 10)
    // note that I have declared a new let constant here, instead of assigning to str
    // because otherwise str.count will be wrong
    let reduced = reduce(str)
    if reduced == "1237"  {
        print(m, "Fib 1237 number is ", a, " | Digits: ", str.count)
        m+=1
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1 Fib 1237 number is  317811  | Digits:  6
2 Fib 1237 number is  2178309  | Digits:  7
3 Fib 1237 number is  267914296  | Digits:  9
4 Fib 1237 number is  701408733  | Digits:  9
5 Fib 1237 number is  1134903170  | Digits:  10
6 Fib 1237 number is  72723460248141  | Digits:  14
7 Fib 1237 number is  117669030460994  | Digits:  15
8 Fib 1237 number is  8944394323791464  | Digits:  16
9 Fib 1237 number is  14472334024676221  | Digits:  17
10 Fib 1237 number is  37889062373143906  | Digits:  17
11 Fib 1237 number is  420196140727489673  | Digits:  18
12 Fib 1237 number is  1100087778366101931  | Digits:  19
13 Fib 1237 number is  1779979416004714189  | Digits:  19
14 Fib 1237 number is  2880067194370816120  | Digits:  19
15 Fib 1237 number is  19740274219868223167  | Digits:  20
16 Fib 1237 number is  83621143489848422977  | Digits:  20
17 Fib 1237 number is  927372692193078999176  | Digits:  21
18 Fib 1237 number is  781774079430987230203437  | Digits:  24
19 Fib 1237 number is  1264937032042997393488322  | Digits:  25
20 Fib 1237 number is  19134702400093278081449423917  | Digits:  29
21 Fib 1237 number is  1983924214061919432247806074196061  | Digits:  34
22 Fib 1237 number is  8404037832974134882743767626780173  | Digits:  34
23 Fib 1237 number is  162926777992448823780908130212788963731840407743629812913410  | Digits:  60
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect solution! You are great!